# Change font size inside a div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing multiple elements. Whenever the user hovers on the div, I want to grow the font size inside that div. The HTML code is as follows:

```
        <div class="col-sm-5 home-grid-2x">
            <div class="home-grid-2" style="right: 0%; top: 0%;">
                <div class="overlay" style="top: 99.9898%; left: -99.9224%;"></div>
                <a class="tile" href="/#/apply">
                <span class="tile-text">
                    Memmbership Application
                </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you see, the hierarchy is as follows:

> ```
> -> home-grid-2x
> ----> home-grid-2
> ----> overlay
> ----> tile
> ------->  tile-text
> ```

Basically, I want yo grow the text size of `tile-text` when user hovers on `home-grid-2x`. I tried the following:

```
.home-grids:hover .tile {
    text-size:150%;
}

.home-grids:hover .tile.tile-text {
    text-size:150%;
}

.home-grids:hover tile-text {
    text-size:150%;
}
```

However none worked. Is that possible?

Comment: The property is `font-size`, not `text-size`.

Comment: It´s not text-size is `font-size`

Comment: It's still the same. Ok I changed it to font-size but I think there is another thing I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this ( use the existing selectors ):

**CSS**

```
.home-grid-2x:hover .tile-text {
   font-size:150%;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1p4bhs3w/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong CSS property.

Instead of `text-size` use `font-size`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Like so:

```
.home-grid-2x:hover .tile {
    font-size:150%;
}

.home-grids-2x:hover .tile.tile-text {
    font-size:150%;
}

.home-grids-2x:hover tile-text {
    font-size:150%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong CSS and wrong selectors buddy !

```css
.home-grid-2x:hover .tile-text {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-5 home-grid-2x">
  <div class="home-grid-2" style="right: 0%; top: 0%;">
    <div class="overlay" style="top: 99.9898%; left: -99.9224%;"></div>
    <a class="tile" href="/#/apply">
      <span class="tile-text">
                    Memmbership Application
                </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :hover

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 home-grid-2x">
        <div class="home-grid-2" style="right: 0%; top: 0%;">
            <div class="overlay" style="top: 99.9898%; left: -99.9224%;"></div>
            <a class="tile" href="/#/apply">
            <span class="tile-text">
                Memmbership Application
            </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.title-text:hover {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c80ndxc4/)